# Node's process.argv not showing all the Node CLI options used

Tags: node.js

I noticed that when running `node --preserve-symlinks some_file.js` and when `some_file.js` prints out the `process.argv`, then the `--preserve-symlinks` flag is not contained in that array. This seems to be the case for other [Node.js CLI options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html). For example I don't see `--prof` when running `node --prof some_file.js`.

Is this a bug, intentionally left out, or do I need to access the node CLI's flag with some other API than argv?

I'm using the snappy node package v12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API I was looking for is called

`process.execArgv`

[Documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execargv)

Comment: Good job following up with the solution